# How to return a specific row to the Bottom from a SQL Query results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple sql query which return the data as

```
select [BusinessModel], count(*) As Total from DimHotelExpand
group by [BusinessModel]
```

The result comes as:

```
DA        53894
DL        7098
ECM       1472
Flex      14789
GDS       33487
Lead      1499050
MT        71306
Unknown   572467
```

I want the row with value 'Lead' to appear at the bottom of the result. How can I do this?

Comment: What's the logic behind `Lead` appear at the bottom?

Comment: You can add: Order By Total to your select statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this, if you don't know if Lead has always the biggest value:

```
select 
    [BusinessModel], count(*) As Total 
from DimHotelExpand
group by 
    [BusinessModel] 
order by 
    case [BusinessModel] when 'Lead' then 1 else 0 end asc
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
      d.BusinessModel
    , Total = COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.DimHotelExpand d
GROUP BY d.BusinessModel
ORDER BY 
      CASE WHEN d.BusinessModel = 'Lead' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    , Total
```

Comment: But arent we assuming that Total would be highest for leads each time here?

Answer (score 1):

You can order it by your total column (since Lead's count is higher) like this:

```
SELECT [BusinessModel], count(*) As Total from DimHotelExpand
GROUP BY [BusinessModel]
ORDER BY count(*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with "union all".

```
select [BusinessModel], count(*) As Total from DimHotelExpand
where [BusinessModel] <> 'Lead'
group by [BusinessModel] 
union all
select [BusinessModel], count(*) As Total from DimHotelExpand
where [BusinessModel] = 'Lead'
group by [BusinessModel]
```

A solution with "Order by", I believe don't work fine. Only work fine while "Lead" is more greater bussines model.

I think frikozoid solution is also valid.

Comment: There is no guarantee that this will show the row with `Lead` in the end.

Comment: I think that is true for the clause "union", because first sorts the rows to eliminate repeated and also returns rows ordered. But not for the clause "union all", at least in Oracle. (although think frikozoid solution, is the best.)

Comment: Most if not all DBMS behave like this in that matter, most of the time. But not always. My point is that there is no guarantee they will behave this way, always. Because they do it the few thoussand times you tested it, does not mean anything.

Comment: This answer by @AaronBertrand says it all: **[Should all queries where you expect a specific order, include an ORDER BY clause?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39345/should-all-queries-where-you-expect-a-specific-order-include-an-order-by-clause/39348#39348)**

Comment: I don't refute your comment. I am not expert DBMS. I trust in you. ;-)

Comment: I'm not either. But Aaron is an expert.